# Hard to trace real root cause under chrome dev tools

Tags: angularjs

I've changed dozens of controllers, services, and html

And got an  Unknown provider exception

> Unknown provider: bankServiceProvider <- bankService <- BanksBaseCtrl

However, it didn't tell me this is due to which file.

The debug message on chrome console is helpless.

Is there any useful way to trace the buggy source file?

Thanks so much

[image: inline]

```
angular.js:12477 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: bankServiceProvider <- bankService <- BanksBaseCtrl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=bankServiceProvider%20%3C-%20bankService%20%3C-%20BanksBaseCtrl
    at http://dev.co/libs/angular/angular/angular.js:68:12
    at http://dev.co/libs/angular/angular/angular.js:4289:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://dev.co/libs/angular/angular/angular.js:4437:39)
    at http://dev.co/libs/angular/angular/angular.js:4294:45
    at getService (http://dev.co/libs/angular/angular/angular.js:4437:39)
    at Object.invoke (http://dev.co/libs/angular/angular/angular.js:4469:13)
    at extend.instance (http://dev.co/libs/angular/angular/angular.js:9136:34)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://dev.co/libs/angular/angular/angular.js:8248:36)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://dev.co/libs/angular/angular/angular.js:7680:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://dev.co/libs/angular/angular/angular.js:7555:30) <div ui-view="" class="fade-in ng-scope">
﻿
```

Comment: Also if you are using it as a separate file, make sure you include the js file

Answer (score 1):

It means you injected `bankService` into `BanksBaseCtrl` and angular couldn't resolve `bankService`.

Verify that you properly registered `bankService` (with that exact name) with the angular module:

```
angular.module('yourapp').service('bankService',function(){...});
```

or, alternatively, correct the injected service name within `BanksBaseCtrl`.

Comment: Thanks. but I want to know at which file causing this exception. I'm new to angular, don't you think this type of exception is useless. Cause I have to `grep` which file calls the bankService :(

Comment: The file that calls the `bankService` is the file in which `BanksBaseCtrl` is implemented, in the inject part. But this file is not the one causing the problem. Do a search on 'bankService' or "bankService" (including the quotes), and verify that this service is correctly added to the module.
If it is, the file in which you found it is probably not loaded. Verify in the Chrome Dev tools if the script is loaded. Check your script tags or whatever you use to load libs.
However, if it is, you probably made a typo when registering the service, e.g. bank**s**Service instead of bankService.